# How to start Quartz.Schedulejob with Java Singleton Class?

Tags: java, singleton, quartz

I'm trying to start a Quartz CronScheduler with a Java Singleton class. But it's not working like my other classes :/

```
            Trigger readRssFeedsTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("3 * * * * ?")).build();

            JobDetail readRss = JobBuilder.newJob(ReadTest.class).build();

            scheduler.scheduleJob(readRss, readRssFeedsTrigger);
```

which throws the following error:

```
The method newJob(Class<? extends Job>) in the type JobBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Class<ReadTest>)
```

My singleton class I'm trying to schedule:

```
    private static final ReadTest instance = new ReadTest();

    // private constructor to avoid client applications to use constructor
    private ReadTest() {
    }

    public static ReadTest getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
```

Expected outcome would be to run my Singleton class every 15 minutes past the whole hour. Which I want to run a public method of my Singleton Class.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it the following way, maybe a bit hacky - but it works and doesn't break the singleton.

```
public class RssStarter implements Job {
    private static ReadTest r = ReadTest.getInstance();

    public RssStarter() {

    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        r.readFeeds();
    }

}
```

Comment: Well you basically adhered to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> The method `newJob(Class<? extends Job>)` in the type `JobBuilder` is not
>   applicable for the arguments (`Class<ReadTest>`)

What this error is telling you has nothing to do with it being a *singleton*.
This says the *expected* input argument must be a class which implements `org.quartz.Job`.

---

The notation

```
? extends Job
```

Means exactly that.
Thus, your `ReadTest` class must implement it.

```
public class ReadTest implements Job {
   // ... Other code omitted

   @Override
   public void execute(final JobExecutionContext context) {
      ...
   }
}
```

And, it must have a `public` no-arg constructor, thus

```
public ReadTest() {}
```

Now you'll be able to call `newJob`

```
JobBuilder.newJob(ReadTest.class)
```

Comment: The singleton patterns means exactly that I cannot have a public no-arg constructor cause that would void the entire singleton :/

Comment: @Edo well that's how Quartz works. The singleton wouldn't hold true anyway, as quartz creates intances as it likes better.